# NodeJS Express - render page updates automatically

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a backend NodeJS code where I gather output from a spawned process:

```
    schild.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    var result = data.toString().split("\n");
    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
            var n = result[i].split("|");
            if(n.length == 4)
            {
                    var date = n[0];
                    var category = n[1];
                    var component = n[2];
                    var condition = n[3];
                    response.push({Date : date, Category : category, Component : component, Condition : condition});
            }
    }
    logger.info('Rendering : ' + response.length);
    res.render('viewpage', {status:0, msg:'Success', responsedata:response});
```

});

My viewpage.ejs file has below code:

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({"bDestroy" : true, "bUseRendered": false, "bSort" : false, "bPaginate" : true, "bDeferRender": true, "iDisplayLength" : 27});
var status = <%= status %>;
if(status == 2)
{
alert( '<%= msg %>' );
}
if(status == 0)
{
<% for(var i =0; i < responsedata.length; i++){ %>
        $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData(['<%= responsedata[i].Date %>', '<%= responsedata[i].Category %>' , '<%= responsedata[i].Component %>', '<%= responsedata[i].Condition %>']);
<% } %>
        oTable.fnDraw();
}
        } );
```

The issue is that the page gets rendered only for the first call to 'res.render' but I wish to update the page with further output as captured in 'schild.stdout.on' event. I do see within my logger statements that first time the response array is of 0 length which is correct but subsequently I get valid data and render to the view - but the page does not gets updated with latest data. The page only loads once and no further updates occurs on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you'll need a different design to make this work. Something like [socket.io](http://socket.io/) can help with streaming data from the server to the browser, but you'll want to do it along the lines of:

1. Render a basic HTML page with empty data and javascript to handle socket.io
2. From javascript in the browser, make a socket.io connection and request your data stream
3. Using code similar to what you have, convert the server subprocess's output `data` events into socket.io messages as a single unit of data is avalable
4. In the browser as each unit of data arrives from the server, format it into HTML and append it into your table.